# Change user on 11.10 hangs system

Tags: 11.10, freeze

When a user locks the screen and another user tries to enter, the system first paints the white space for the password textbox, but doesn't put the cursor in it. Afterwards, no textbox appears, so the first user cannot enter the system neither.

System shutdown or restart doesn't seem to work neither, so the only option is a hard reboot (maintain the power button pushed until the computer powers down).

The question is if there is a way to prevent this from happening (without having to logout every time)?

Just filed a bug report in Launchpad.

Comment: I am also getting this -- please post the link to the Launchpad bug

Comment: is this it? https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity-greeter/+bug/835310

Comment: @SpashHit: [This is it](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-video-intel/+bug/883783). But I think it's the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem.  I followed the suggestion in the [Launchpad bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity-greeter/+bug/835310) and removed the `libpam-smbpass` package with this command:

```
sudo apt-get remove libpam-smbpass
```

This fixed the problem. However, you should read the bug report about the repercussions of removing this package.  It has something to do with `Samba` (file sharing) and password synching, but I don't totally understand it myself.  If anyone here can explain it better in a comment, I would appreciate it (i.e. from the point of view of a user, what behavior would I experience exactly after removing the package and what exactly would I have to do to work around it)

Comment: Did it, tested it, and it works! I was going to ditch Samba anyway because I'm not using it. Samba is a fileshare for Windows.

Comment: It is not just for Windows... you can use Samba to share files between 2 Linux computers

Comment: Sure, but you can use NFS as well. I've no idea about the password synching though.